# Excel copying part of a string between characters

Tags: excel

Is there a way of returning part of a string between certain characters in excel? For example my string looks like this:

```
`switchrefid` = {switchrefid: }
```

I need to cut the part of the string between the ' (apostrophes) so it just returns switchrefid

I'm sure there must be a formula for this i just cant think of the one to use.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `'` = apostrophe = single quote, `\`` = backtick = backquote, `´` = accute accent (used only as s diacritic, not as quotes)

Comment: The back-tick/back-quote is the apostrophe in this case, but thank you for clarifying that for me haha my English isn't that good today :)

Comment: note that an apostrophe as the 1st character in Excel is by default not displayed, but used to mark the following content as text, e.g. `'1.0` would display text `1.0` without any automatic modifications and aligned to the left by default... and `=find("'", A1)` won't find this first apostrophe

Comment: @deathApril, Excel finds that first apostrophe for me, as long as there is also another apostrophe following (which there is in the OP's question).

Comment: @Vicky with `'` as the first character - not `\`dd\``, `(space)'dd'` or `="'dd'"`? and the find returns 1?

Comment: @deathApril, doh, sorry, no. You're right. I was confusing two different tests that I did.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as the ``` characters occur exactly twice in your data, you can do:

```
=LEFT(RIGHT(A1, LEN(A1)-FIND("`", A1)), FIND("`",RIGHT(A1, LEN(A1)-FIND("`", A1)))-1)
```

Although it is pretty horrible!

(Edit: this assumes your data is in A1, of course.)

Comment: Your answer is 100% im sure i can fix it up abit and make it less complex but i actually found something that i was looking at http://www.excelfunctions.net/split-string-in-excel.html which had the basic concept of what you just said. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Just two more options, if the word always starts at the second Character and ends just before the last you could simply use :

```
=MID(A1,2,LEN(A1)-2) ' Minus 2 for the 2 ticks
```

And the second option would be to substitute the tick with nothing like so:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(A1,"`","")
```

With the substitute is also supports a number of substitutes. So if you had `switchrefid`` for some reason and only want to get rid of 2 of the three ticks you could use:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(A1,"`","",2)
```

and this would return switchrefid`

although it would not work for ''switchrefid' as it would STILL return switchrefid' because it only removes the 1st 2 instances of the text to remove