# excel - get string between "-" chars

Tags: excel

I have cells which represents some RGB colors in this format:

**RRR-GGG-BBB**

You can see that each color is separated by "-" sign.

What I need is to get the "GGG" DATA, For example if I have:
12-1-256 - the output cell should be "1".

Please note that the colors are not always 3 chars, they can be also 2 or 1.

I have tried to use the MID function without success, this gives me always three chars (as I defined...)

=MID(E2,SEARCH("-",E2,1)+1,3)

Thank you

Comment: If it doesn't have to be a formula solution then, see: [How to parse data using the Text To Columns command in Excel](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/214261)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick, depending on your language settings you might need to change `;` by `,`

```
=LEFT(RIGHT(A1; LEN(A1)-FIND("-"; A1)); FIND("-";RIGHT(A1; LEN(A1)-FIND("-"; A1)))-1)
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16193247/excel-copying-part-of-a-string-between-characters)

Answer (score 2):

You need to use FIND() to get the indices of - characters and then LEFT() and RIGHT() to extract characters between those indices.

For example, if your string is in cell A1, you could do this:

```
Set B1 to =FIND("-",A1)                ' gives you index of first -
set C1 to =LEFT(A1,B1-1)               ' gives you RRR
set D1 to =RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-B1)       ' gives you GGG-BBB
set E1 to =FIND("-",D1)                ' gives you index of second -
set F1 to =LEFT(D1,E1-1)               ' gives you GGG
set G1 to =RIGHT(D1,LEN(D1)-E1)        ' gives you BBB
```

If you prefer, you can of course combine these into a single formula to get just GGG by substituting back the parts of the formula I gave above, like this:

```
set B1 to =LEFT(RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND("-",A1)),FIND("-",RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND("-",A1)))-1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`=TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"-",REPT(" ",999)),2*999-998,999))`

`"-"` - is the delimiter,and `2` - is the second item.

See [this](http://www.excelfox.com/forum/f22/get-field-from-delimited-text-string-333/) for explanation.